# Detect Whether Or Not Video Clip Is Copy Protected

Tags: swift, macos, avkit, avplayerview

I have a desktop (macOS) application that reads video clips (.mov, .m4v, .mp4...).  The application reads a video clip as an `avAsset` object as follows.

```
import Cocoa
import AVKit

class VideoViewController: NSViewController {
    var videoPlayer: AVPlayer!
    var videoURL: URL?
    var videoDur: Double!
    var videoFrameRate: Float!
    var videoData: Data!
    var naturalSize: CGSize!
    var hasVideo = false

    @IBOutlet weak var moviePlayer: AVPlayerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var layerView: LayerView!

    func readVideoClip(url: URL) {
        let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
        let videoTracks = avAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)
        if videoTracks.count > 0 {
            let videoTrack = videoTracks[0]
            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)
            let avFrameRate = videoTrack.nominalFrameRate
            videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
            moviePlayer.player = videoPlayer
            moviePlayer.isHidden = false
            naturalSize = videoTrack.naturalSize

            /* variables */
            hasVideo = true
            videoURL = url
            videoDur = totalDuration
            videoFrameRate = avFrameRate
        }
    }
}
```

My question is whether or not there is a way of telling whether or not the selected video clip is copy-protected.  The application is already available at Mac App Store.  I've submitted a software update for it.  And they've rejected it by saying the following.

> We found the app allows the user to select copy protected files such
>   as .m4v and does not inform the user that the file cannot be
>   converted/saved/revised.

It seems that `AVPlayerView` has `canBeginTrimming` property.  And the following returns `false` with a non-protected video clip.

```
if !moviePlayer.canBeginTrimming {
       // it returns false      
}
```

I guess an extreme measure will be to not accept the M4V format when the user selects a video clip.  Thanks.

Comment: it might be a `hasProtectedContent` property of AVAsset class - `A Boolean value that indicates whether the asset has protected content`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasset/1389223-hasprotectedcontent

Comment: @John  I think you are right except that there is no way of my confirming it since I have no DRM-protected clips.  Anyway, I will accept it if you submit that as a solution.